# How can I set the "type" parameter on a Web API MultiPartContent message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, content-type, multipart

I need to be able to set the Content-Type value for a multipart response to:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type=application/dicom; boundary={MessageBoundary}
```

This is defined in an international standard, so I have no choice in it, and I see that the use of "type=xxx/yyy" is standard usage to define the "main" content type in a MultiPart message.

BUT......I have not managed to find a way to produce this string using the otherwise excellent MultipartContent class in the web API.  I've tried:

1) Doing nothing - hoping that it gets picked up from the first item in the content - it doesn't

2) Setting as part of the subtype - e.g.:

```
MultipartContent mpc = new MultipartContent("related; type=application/dicom+xml");
```

this fails with the error "The format of value 'multipart/related; type=application/dicom+xml' is invalid."

3) Setting explicitly as another parameter on the MediaTypeHeadervalue:

```
var mthv = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/related");
mthv.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("type", "application/dicom+xml"));
```

this gives the same error :-(

Am I missing something obvious here, or is there really no way to indicate the associated type?

*UPDATE*:

After some research, and decompiling the NameValueHeaderValue class, it seems that the problem is the / and + characters in the type value - as the constructor for NameValueHeaderValue checks both the name and the token to see whether their native and "token characters only" versions have the same length - i.e. whether they include any non-token characters - and reject them if that's the case.  Given that the standard values for the type value are MIME types, which by definition include a / character, this does seem to be an overly and inappropriately strict constraint.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in that the problem is in the `/` and `+` characters in the type value, but .NET is not entirely wrong in rejecting your input (I might wish that this part of the API were better engineered, but what do I know). RFC 2045, which specifies MIME, section 5.1, says that the parameter values must be quoted if they contain any of `()<>@,;:\"/[]?=`. RFC 2387, which describes the multipart/related content type, says that *the parameter values will usually require quoting* and the example they give has the subordinate content type value properly quoted. As for your concrete problem, e.g. this ought to work:

```
var mpc = new MultipartContent ("related") ;
var nvv = new NameValueHeaderValue ("type", "\"application/dicom+xml\"") ;
mpc.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add (nvv) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. .... Just what i needed. .... Now i need to get the modifications into the DICOM standard!

Comment: Your consumers don't understand the response if the subordinate type is quoted as per RFC?

Comment: I don't know yet, as I'm still testing against my own implementation for now......my wish to fix the standard is to avoid others making the same mistake as I did!

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with a similar issue and this did the trick.

It appears that for the DICOM STOW-RS service the DICOM standard currently specifies the Content-Type header to contain `"multipart/related; type=application/dicom; boundary={messageBoundary}"`. This is apparently wrong and should be `"multipart/related; type="application/dicom"; boundary={messageBoundary}"`.

I had problem with the method `HttpContentMultipartExtensions.IsMimeMultipartContent()` returning false and having the HttpContent.Headers values empty when I had the Content-Type type parameter containing `type=application/dicom`.

Using `type="application/dicom"` made it work.